# Why does my vim status line say "Obtaining ../"?

Tags: text-processing, vim, notifications

On the righthand side of my vim status line it says "Obtaining ../" and is highlighted yellow. Why does it say this?

The results of :set are:

```
:set
--- Options ---
  cpoptions=BceFs     history=1000        incsearch         nomodeline            pastetoggle=<F2>    ruler               shiftwidth=4        tabstop=4           ttymouse=xterm2
  helplang=en         ignorecase          laststatus=2        number              report=10000        scroll=30           smartcase           ttyfast
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  fileencoding=utf-8
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  formatprg=astyle -A2T4pDU
  printoptions=paper:letter
  runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim73,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
  statusline=%f %h%m%r%=%9*Obtaining ../
  suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg,.inx,.out,.toc
```

Comment: try `vim -V1` to see what's going on and check the status line plugins you installed

Comment: I have not installed any plugins (other than what comes with the default install)

Comment: try `vim -u None` (which means run without any config) to see if "Obtaining ../" still there. You might also want to post your vim version and your OS so others might be able to help

Comment: OS is Debian linux. I think I may have accidentally pressed one of the keys on the numeric key pad to cause it. I know I can probably get rid of it by restarting, but I don't want to get rid of it. I want to know why it is there in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

I found that this happens when I enter netrw (with `:Explore`, for example) and press `O` on a file, it attempts to "obtain" this file resulting in an error message and this text being appended to my status line. I haven't found a way to get rid of it other than to use `:set`, copy out the normal status line, and re-set my status line to the proper one without "Obtaining". Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in two lines from your given `:set` output:

```
runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim73,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
statusline=%f %h%m%r%=%9*Obtaining ../
```

Somewhere, your statusline is being altered to contain `Obtaining ../`. Unless this is a stock vim thing (which I doubt, or at least don't recognise as being so), one of those directories will contain the responsible file.

Alas, we do not have access to the files on your machine, and hence a more exact reason may be something only you can determine.